# Overwrite constraint constant in subview

Tags: ios, swift

Hey I have a subview that I add to my view controller like so in `viewDidLoad`:

```
stretchyHeaderView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! MyHeaderView;
stretchyHeaderView.maximumContentHeight = 160;
stretchyHeaderView.minimumContentHeight = 64;
stretchyHeaderView.contentExpands = false
tableView.addSubview(stretchyHeaderView)
```

Inside this view is a label with a constraint pinning it to the top e.g

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabelTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

I want to override the size of the constant for this constraint for certain situations. e.g `titleLabelTopConstraint.constant = 60`. Where in my code should I do this? I have tried calling it in `layoutIfNeeded` and `layoutSubviews` but I get a nil unwrap crash `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. An pointers on this would be great! Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide exact crash error message? And also give a try using `strong` IBOutlet instead of `weak` one.

Comment: setUpStrecthyHeaderView() when you call @KexAri

Comment: Did you connect the outlet to the view in IB?